# Multiple commands not found in Terminal after homebrew install attempt -- reset PATH?

Tags: path, command-line-arguments, homebrew

This started when I was trying to install homebrew.  I'm very new to all of this so I apologize in advance if I do not explain this with the correct vocabulary.

I initially ran `brew doctor` and got `command not found`.  After scouring some forums and changing $PATH, I at least got to the point where `brew doctor` gave me a warning suggesting I remove part of $PATH.  Unfortunately I can't remember exactly which part--something starting with "/opt."

I removed some of the $PATH but am now unable to run basic commands such as:

```
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ irb
-bash: irb: command not found
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ open ~/.bash_profile
-bash: open: command not found
```

Now my brew doctor attempts look like this:

```
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ brew doctor
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 2: dirname: command not found
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 5: basename: command not found
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 8: readlink: command not found
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 16: cd: /Users/taytufenkjian/../Library: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 18: uname: command not found
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 18: tr: command not found
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 23: exec: ruby: not found
```

I thought I'd try to reset my $PATH but the commands I keep trying give me the "command not found" message.

$PATH details:

```
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/taytufenkjian/
```

I've been at this for a couple of hours and I'm so confused.  I'm trying to set up my environment for a class that starts in a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was actually able to get some outside help on this.

For other newbies reading this, I created a new .bash_profile and saved over the existing one.

I added this line to the .bash_profile:
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

So editing .bashrc didn't work but creating a new .bash_profile and editing that did work.

Answer (score 20):

It is happens when you just copy the line (below) into the .bash_profile without removing the quotes (**'**xxxx**'**)

`export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH'`

To resolve, just run in console:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Then, edit again the file removing the quotes:

`vim ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Your path should look something a little more like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

In order to get this; you really shouldn't have to do much except this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Put that into your ~/.bashrc.

Start a new terminal session and try it out.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to edit .bashrc in the terminal or use the terminal to view hidden files, so I opened a text editor and saved over the .bashrc that was already there.  I reopened the terminal but nothing seems to have changed.  Basic commands like ls still aren't working.  Posting the code separately because it's too long.

Comment: `Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/taytufenkjian/
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/taytufenkjian/`

Comment: `Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ touch ~/.bashrc
-bash: touch: command not found
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ nano ~/.bashrc
-bash: nano: command not found
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$ ls -a
-bash: ls: command not found
Tays-MacBook-Pro:~ taytufenkjian$`

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the quotes, but closing and re-launching my terminal is what ultimately confirmed the change had worked.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't create new `.barsh_profile` or any other file starting with . using  `TextEdit`. So, to restore terminal settings, I run '. `/etc/profile`'. After that I was able to run other commands, and create/remove/modify `.*` system files.